# Can I make both images with different opacity's on jquery hover

Tags: jquery, css, hover, z-index

I am trying to make the small plus rounded button to be with full opacity and still clickable on my effect
At the moment it is taking the opacity for the whole link (which i would like to stay like that), if i change the z-index it goes on top of the link but then it is not launching the fancybox.

```
.img-hover > a  {
    position:relative;
}
.img-hover {
    display:inline-block;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.img-hover .hover {
    display:none;
    background:#000;
    border-radius:50px;
    height:35px;
    width:30px;
    font-size:42px;
    font-weight:bold;
    color:#fff;
    padding:10px 15px 20px 20px;
    position:absolute;
    cursor:pointer;
    right:180px;
    top:180px;
}
```

Here is the jsfiddle i created http://jsfiddle.net/W9uju/1/

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set `z-index` and then use this snippet:

```
$(function() {
    $(".img-hover").hover(
        function() {
            $(this).children("a").fadeTo(200, 0.5).end().children(".hover").show();
        },
        function() {
            $(this).children("a").fadeTo(200, 1).end().children(".hover").hide();
        });
}).on('click',function(e){
    if($(e.target).hasClass('hover'))
        $(this).find('.fancybox')[0].click();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/W9uju/2/)

On modern browsers, you could set `pointer-events:none;` too

[DEMO pointer-events](http://jsfiddle.net/W9uju/3/)

Comment: @FezVrasta but then clicking on .hover element doesn't open fancybox as it is expected

Comment: facybox works as expected, just apply the right link to it, I've removed them.

Comment: @FezVrasta I mean anchor click is not fired if clicking on `<i>` in your example because event won't propagate to anchor tag as it is a sibling of clicked element.

Comment: @FezVrasta and then you fallback to my second solution

Comment: @FezVrasta which jsfiddle? /7/?  OK /8/ i think, i'll check

Comment: @FezVrasta ya will work if OP doesn't matter to modificate is HTML code and IMO, would be better for sure to use only CSS when possible

Answer (score 1):

Edit:

sorry, I've understood the opposite of what you re looking for, here an example with what you need:

http://jsfiddle.net/W9uju/9/

---

<s>Use `rgba` or `hsla` as `background color`:</s>

```
rgba(0,0,0,0.5);

rgba(
  0,  // R red
  0,  // G green
  0,  // B blue
  0.5 // A alpha
)

hsla(0,0%,0%,0.5);

hsla(
  0,  // H hue
  0%, // S saturation
  0%, // L lightness
  0.5 // A alpha
)
```

To provide fallback compatibility you should write:

```
background-color: #000; /* Old browsers (IE8<) */
background-color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0.5); /* Modern browsers */
```