# Changing Form Field Opacity in Bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, bootstrap-4

I've tried a few different things and I can't seem to figure out how to change the opacity of the placeholder without the opacity for the text input to be included.

Here is the code:

```html
<label for="CI_company-organization-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label" style="margin-top: 5px;" required>Company/Organization</label>
   <div class="col-lg-8">
     <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CI_company-organization-input" placeholder="Ex: GreyBar">
   </div>
```

I want to make the opacity of the placeholder to be 0.5 but make the text input to be normal opacity. I've tried placing a style tag after the placeholder attribute but all that does it make the opacity of the input text also 0.5 opacity.

Is this possible?

Comment: Try change background to rgba color (256,256,256,0.5) in your case

Comment: [You have that question already, check here -->] https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18721382/how-do-you-make-an-input-field-opacity-not-effect-the-text-color-inside-it?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa

Comment: Thanks for the input guys, got the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a possible solution with some fallbacks

https://codepen.io/gurgen/full/Kemeyv

```
<label for="CI_company-organization-input" class="col-lg-10 col-form-label" style="margin-top: 5px;" required>Company/Organization</label>
<div class="col-lg-8">
    <input class="form-control" type="text" id="CI_company-organization-input" placeholder="Ex: GreyBar">
</div>
```

Here is the CSS

```
input.form-control::placeholder { /* Chrome, Firefox, Opera, Safari 10.1+ */
    color: red;
    opacity: .5; /* Firefox */
}

input.form-control:-ms-input-placeholder { /* Internet Explorer 10-11 */
    color: red;
    opacity: .5;
}
input.form-control::-ms-input-placeholder { /* Microsoft Edge */
    color: red;
    opacity: .5;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the help @Gurgen!

Answer (score 2):

You maybe want to try this and le               t me know if it works?

```
input.form-control::placeholder {
    opacity: .5;
}
```